# How to run locust from command line without disabling locust web UI

Tags: performance, web-api-testing, locust

How to run locust from command line without disabling locust web UI?

As per the locust documentation

> To start tests directly, without using the web interface, use --headless.
> ref : https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/quickstart.html?#more-options

But this would disable the web UI. How to start tests directly but also keep the web UI ?

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much a bug/missing feature atm. Right now your answer is an appropriate workaround, but hopefully someone will fix it some time as it shouldnt be too hard...

Answer (score 2):

Start locust by using cmd `locust` or `locust -f <locustfilename.py>`

To trigger the test using cmd and also keep the locust web UI I found the below workaround .

Trigger the test using the /swarm url

```
curl -X POST   http://localhost:8089/swarm   -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'   -d 'user_count='10'&spawn_rate='1'&host='http://localhost:8080'
```

To end, use /stop url

```
curl http://localhost:8089/stop
```

It will be easy to build a script with the above curls to trigger `/swarm` the test, then sleep for a period of time (run duration) and then stop the test using `/stop`.

This way the locust web UI will also be available unlike the `--headless` mode.

Comment: How do we trigger command line argument on remote server. for ex. with above approach only 3 fields can be passed in body namely host, spawn rate and host. what about rest fields?

Comment: What are the other attributes your referring to?  The above curl example has all the same parameters to trigger the test as in UI.